# Remote call and caching inside ksqldb udf

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

Trying to figure out if it’s possible and/or correct to define a ksqldb UDF (user-defined function) that would make a remote call to a service and cache the result somewhere?

I think the RPC part is pretty straight-forward but I’m not sure if the UDF class can have a state (talking about the simplest case of a “scalar” function) where I can store cache and ideally a gRPC channel instance.

I know I could use Kafka Streams easily but it’s really just a simple call, wouldn’t want to deploy another service just for this.

Comment: There's nothing preventing that from happening, but it may affect other time sensitive functions that ksqlDB / kafka streams needs for windowing, for example. The alternative is to do that remote call elsewhere, then get results into a topic that ksqlDB can join against

Comment: @OneCricketeer do you mean affect because there's gonna be a blocking network call? That part would be fine with me but what do you think about the caching part?

Comment: You'd need to write to disk or off-heap. Such as Redis/sqlite... You won't be able to cache within the JVM of the UDF